Vim suddenly "forgets" whether yanked text was character-wise or line-wise
I have a habit of copying lines of text across files by yanking it, closing Vim, starting Vim with the target file, then p. However, earlier today Vim started to forget that I yanked whole lines of text and started pasting it after the character.
For example, if I have a file with just one line of abcd, when I hit yy then p, it becomes two lines of abcd. When I hit yy, exit and restart Vim, then p, it becomes one line of aabcdbcd.
I have not touched my vimrc for months and looking in my home directory for recently modified files, I couldn't find anything related to Vim. I have tried deleting ~/.viminfo and the undesired behavior persists. How can I restore Vim to its old behavior?

This is Ubuntu's stock Vim:
# vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.1 (2024 Jan 02, compiled May 03 2024 02:45:42)
Included patches: 1-16

# apt list vim-nox
vim-nox/noble-updates,now 2:9.1.0016-1ubuntu7.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]

I'm working over SSH from a Windows 10 PC, using Windows Terminal and Win10's stock OpenSSH, and this Vim runs inside a tmux session.

I was going to recommend checking the viminfo option, but there doesn’t appear to be a tweak for this. I wonder if it could be a bug; are you able to build from source and bisect? What version are you using?

Ubuntu/WSL or normal Ubuntu? KDE/Gnome/xyz ? What is clipboard manager? Klipper or what? What is "stock vim"? Vim-gtk3 or which one? Your question lacks almost every bit of vital info.

Does this also happen in vim --clean? I wonder if it might be related to some plug-in or clipboard integration you might have in your vimrc or other initialization config file

Actually, under vim -u NONE which disables the initialization via vimrc, perhaps vim -u NONE --noplugin, it turns out -i disables loading viminfo so that wouldn't help, but you can disable vimrc and plugins to see if that has an effect as expected

Thanks to @filbranden's hint, I identified vimtmuxclipboard.vim as the culprit. Disabling this plugin restored Vim's behavior.
I still have no idea why it broke out of the blue. It used to work perfectly and I have touched neither Vim nor tmux.

To me it looks like there's a bug in this line that implements TextYankPost, it joins a list with newlines but doesn't append a newline at the end, the effect of the bug would be exactly what you described.

Or, more likely, code in s:on_stdout() which is triggered right at startup, it has the same bug of joining a list with newlines without adding another newline at the end. I don't know if this can be called a bug because Vim has this concept of charwise/linewise registers and I'm not sure the clipboard is the same.
